# What is the use of Accessible mode, Skip to main and Turn Off Animations options in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, accessibility

While we use SharePoint 2013 with keyboard only, we come across few options while we keep on pressing TAB key on top left corner in blue bar (`just on top of SuiteBar`)

These Options are as follows

**1.** Turn on more accessible mode

[image]

**2.** Skip to main content

[image]

**3.** Turn off animations

[image]

I have never user these options, so I would like to know how are they useful? When should we recommend these options to users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every SharePoint page has three links that are the first options on the page. You access the links only by using the Tab key.

- Turn on more accessible mode – Enables More Accessible Mode
- Skip Ribbon Commands – Skips active focus past the ribbon commands, and moves the focus directly to the navigation links
- Skip to main content – Skips both the ribbon commands and the navigation links, and moves the focus directly to the main content area of the page.

Check [Accessibility features in SharePoint products](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Accessibility-features-in-SharePoint-products-f291404a-dc7e-44de-a31f-d81b3099c2b9#__toc346615671)